# upset plot with set size bars in right side

Tags: r, upsetr

The UpSetR R package offers a wonderful method to upgrade the traditional Venn-diagram when multiple components/sets are to be compared. However, the upset plot in R (using UpSetR package) plots the set size (horizontal bars) on the left side of the plot. Is there any way to make them on the right side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moving horizontal bars from the left to the right side is not straightforward.
 To achieve this, you should make adjustments to the `Make_size_plot` and `NoAttBasePlot` functions within the `UpSetR` package. 
 The suggested modifications are indicated below with comments (`# Modified` for your convenience) preceding each changed line of code.

```
library(UpSetR)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
library(ggplot2)

NoAttBasePlot <- function (legend, size_plot_height, Main_bar_plot, Matrix_plot, 
    hratios, Size_plot, query_legend, set_metadata, set_metadata_plots, 
    newpage) {
    top <- 1
    bottom <- 100
    if ((!is.null(legend)) && (query_legend != tolower("none"))) {
        if (query_legend == tolower("top")) {
            top <- 3
            bottom <- 102
            legend_top <- 1
            legend_bottom <- 3
            size_plot_height <- (size_plot_height + 2)
        }
        else if (query_legend == tolower("bottom")) {
            legend_top <- 101
            legend_bottom <- 103
        }
    }
    if (is.null(set_metadata)) {
        matrix_and_mainbar_right <- 100
        matrix_and_mainbar_left <- 21
        size_bar_right <- 20
        size_bar_left <- 1
    }
    else if (!is.null(set_metadata)) {
        matrix_and_mainbar_right <- set_metadata$ncols + 100
        matrix_and_mainbar_left <- set_metadata$ncols + 21
        size_bar_right <- set_metadata$ncols + 20
        size_bar_left <- set_metadata$ncols + 1
        metadata_right <- set_metadata$ncols
        metadata_left <- 1
    }
    if (newpage) {
        grid::grid.newpage()
    }
    if ((!is.null(legend)) && (query_legend != tolower("none"))) {
        if (query_legend == tolower("top")) {
            pushViewport(viewport(layout = grid.layout(102, matrix_and_mainbar_right)))
        }
        else if (query_legend == tolower("bottom")) {
            pushViewport(viewport(layout = grid.layout(103, matrix_and_mainbar_right)))
        }
    }
    else if ((is.null(legend)) || (query_legend == tolower("none"))) {
        pushViewport(viewport(layout = grid.layout(100, matrix_and_mainbar_right)))
    }
    # Modified
    vp = UpSetR:::vplayout(top:bottom, 1:(matrix_and_mainbar_right-matrix_and_mainbar_left))
    pushViewport(vp)
    grid.draw(arrangeGrob(Main_bar_plot, Matrix_plot, heights = hratios))
    popViewport()
    # Modified
    vp = UpSetR:::vplayout(size_plot_height:bottom, (matrix_and_mainbar_right-matrix_and_mainbar_left-1):96)
    pushViewport(vp)
    grid.draw(arrangeGrob(Size_plot))
    popViewport()
    if (!is.null(set_metadata)) {
        for (i in 1:length(set_metadata_plots)) {
            if (i != 1) {
                metadata_left <- 1 + metadata_right
                metadata_right <- metadata_right + set_metadata$plots[[i]]$assign
            }
            else {
                metadata_left <- 1
                metadata_right <- set_metadata$plots[[i]]$assign
            }
            vp = UpSetR:::vplayout(size_plot_height:bottom, metadata_left:metadata_right)
            pushViewport(vp)
            grid.draw(arrangeGrob(set_metadata_plots[[i]]))
            popViewport()
        }
    }
    if ((!is.null(legend)) && (query_legend != tolower("none"))) {
        vp = UpSetR:::vplayout(legend_top:legend_bottom, matrix_and_mainbar_left:matrix_and_mainbar_right)
        pushViewport(vp)
        grid.draw(arrangeGrob(legend))
        popViewport()
    }
}

Make_size_plot <- function (Set_size_data, sbar_color, ratios, ylabel, scale_sets, 
    text_scale, set_size_angle, set_size.show, set_size.scale_max, 
    set_size.number_size) {
    if (length(text_scale) > 1 && length(text_scale) <= 6) {
        x_axis_title_scale <- text_scale[3]
        x_axis_tick_label_scale <- text_scale[4]
    }
    else {
        x_axis_title_scale <- text_scale
        x_axis_tick_label_scale <- text_scale
    }
    if (ylabel == "Set Size" && scale_sets != "identity") {
        ylabel <- paste("Set Size", paste0("( ", 
            scale_sets, " )"))
        if (scale_sets == "log2") {
            Set_size_data$y <- log2(Set_size_data$y)
        }
        if (scale_sets == "log10") {
            Set_size_data$y <- log10(Set_size_data$y)
        }
    }
    if (!is.null(set_size.number_size)) {
        num.size <- (set_size.number_size/2.845276) * x_axis_tick_label_scale
    }
    else {
        num.size <- (7/2.845276) * x_axis_tick_label_scale
    }
    Size_plot <- (ggplot(data = Set_size_data, aes_string(x = "x", 
        y = "y")) + geom_bar(stat = "identity", colour = sbar_color, 
        width = 0.4, fill = sbar_color, position = "identity") + 
        scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0.5, (nrow(Set_size_data) + 
            0.5)), breaks = c(0, max(Set_size_data)), expand = c(0, 
            0)) + theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"), 
        plot.margin = unit(c(-0.11, -1.3, 0.5, 0.5), "lines"), 
        axis.title.x = element_text(size = 8.3 * x_axis_title_scale), 
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 7 * x_axis_tick_label_scale, 
            vjust = 1, hjust = 0.5), axis.line = element_line(colour = "gray0"), 
        axis.line.y = element_blank(), axis.line.x = element_line(colour = "gray0", 
            size = 0.3), axis.text.y = element_blank(), axis.ticks.y = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank()) + 
        xlab(NULL) + ylab(ylabel) + coord_flip())
    if (set_size.show == TRUE) {
        Size_plot <- (Size_plot + geom_text(aes(label = y, vjust = 0.5, 
            hjust = 1.2, angle = set_size_angle), size = num.size))
    }
    if (scale_sets == "log10") {
        if (!is.null(set_size.scale_max)) {
            Size_plot <- (Size_plot + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(set_size.scale_max, 
                0), trans = log10_reverse_trans()))
        }
        else {
            Size_plot <- (Size_plot + scale_y_continuous(trans = log10_reverse_trans()))
        }
    }
    else if (scale_sets == "log2") {
        if (!is.null(set_size.scale_max)) {
            Size_plot <- (Size_plot + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(set_size.scale_max, 
                0), trans = log2_reverse_trans()))
        }
        else {
            Size_plot <- (Size_plot + scale_y_continuous(trans = log2_reverse_trans()))
        }
    }
    else {
        if (!is.null(set_size.scale_max)) {
            Size_plot <- (Size_plot + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(set_size.scale_max, 
                0), trans = "reverse"))
        }
        else {
            # Modified
            #Size_plot <- (Size_plot + scale_y_continuous(trans = "reverse"))
        }
    }
    Size_plot <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(Size_plot))
    return(Size_plot)
}

assignInNamespace(x="NoAttBasePlot", value=NoAttBasePlot, ns="UpSetR")
assignInNamespace(x="Make_size_plot", value=Make_size_plot, ns="UpSetR")

movies <- read.csv(system.file("extdata", "movies.csv", package = "UpSetR"), 
                   header=TRUE, sep=";")
upset(movies, nsets = 7, nintersects = 30, mb.ratio = c(0.5, 0.5),
      order.by = c("freq", "degree"), decreasing = c(TRUE,FALSE))
```

[image]

Comment: That works perfectly. However, there is still one challenge. The set names (Adventure, Horror, ....) are still on the left side.

Comment: @AlemuAssefa OK. I will try to move set names of the right side.

Comment: IS there a way to remove set size bars completely?

Comment: @ktyagi Interesting question. Post your question on StackOverflow. You'll surely get an answer to your problem.